# Securely Passing MongoDB Query to mongoose over API

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an eCommerce website that displays inventory on sites. Inventory can change hourly. The Inventory can be categorized by 'type'

*For example*:
Total Inventory is 150

Total **Type1**: 100
Total **Type2**: 50

In the schema - each document carries this type. I am looking to be able to display these 'sorted' counts on my website.
I need some direction for being able to securely pass mongodb queries to mongoose through an API and return counts of documents returned from the collections. Using typescript!

Comment: Which languages and frameworks are you using for your frontend and backend, that might be helpful inorder to solve this

Comment: Using Typescript !

Comment: Is your backend using express, nestjs or the like, basically which framework.

Comment: We are using NestJS

Comment: Great then, is it possible to post the schema to the question, because this seems to be something you should be able to do in a the service, if I can see how the types "Type1" and "Type2" are inferred I can most probably give a better answer

Comment: Looking to show counts grouped by model '@Schema({ collection: "product", timestamps: true})
export class Product
{
 public readonly _id?: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

 @Prop(() => Date)
 public readonly createdAt?: Date

 @Prop(() => Date)
 public readonly updatedAt?: Date

 @Prop({ unique: true, required: true })
 public upc: string;

 @Prop({ required: true })
 public condition: "New" | "Like New";

 @Prop({ required: true })
 public manufacturer: string;

 @Prop({ required: true })
 public model: string;

 @Prop({ required: true })
 public style: string;

}'

Comment: Sorry - a bit new to using StackOverflow.  not sure what did with the formatting... but we would look to show the inventory counts grouped by Model and Condition. 

So for example - counts for all matching "NEW" and Model "POLO"

I appreciate your help and advice!

Comment: Is there more information I can provide?

Comment: Sorry abit tied up and forgot to come back to this